# this. vs base. for inherited protected non-virtual methods?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, virtual, protected

Whithin my sub-class, should I refer to an inherited protected non-virtual method as `this.Method()` or `base.Method()`?

Using `this` would allow me to easily hide the method with a new method of the same name. Should calls to the method explicitly specifiy `base` only when it is certain that only the base class' implementation specifically needs to be called?

Comment: you should always call this.Method() when calling and do a base::Method() call from within the implemented overridden methods within the derived class.  That way in the future when you override something you don't have to go around doing a base.Method();

Comment: It's not a virtual method and cannot be overridden. Non-virtual methods can only be hidden.

Comment: Why not just refer to it as `Method()`? If `this` hides that with its own `Method()` then that will be called. If not, `base.Method()` will be called. This was chosen to be the default behaviour; probably for good reasons. ^_^

Comment: As it is a Non virtual method there is no functional polymorphism involved.to make it obvious i would go for base.Method.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto - true, but why have a method with the exact same signature, if you don't intend any kind of polimorphism? The only time I'd hide a base method would be if base was closed source and I could not make that method virtual. And if I work with the object from the outside, calling `Method()` would always call the hiding `this.Method()`. Which I would expect to behave in some way related to `base.Method()`.

Comment: @Corak StyleCop requires one or the other unless it's a static method.

Comment: @Kurian - weird, for me, explicitly calling `this.Method()` is less readable. But if StyleCop requires it, I'd go with `this.Method()` because that is the standard behaviour.

Comment: @Kurian you'll do well to disable that StyleCop rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call always using `this.Method()`.

If you hide the method, you'll probably want to call the new method instead of the one in the base class. On the other hand, if you make the base class' method virtual, you'll probably want to make your code to call if in a polymorphic way.

It's hard to predict the future, but these scenarios seems more likely to happen.

Answer (score 7):

If you're ever going to add a member named `Method` in your sub-class and still want to invoke the inherited method, you should use `base.Method()`.
Adding members named `Method` in more derived classes will not change the meaning of `this.Method()` invocation.